# remove permanently eclipse from ubuntu system

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall, eclipse, system, permanent-delete

Please can someone helps me ? I want to delete eclipse from my ubuntu system.
I used the command `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge eclipse` to do that but the message i received is :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'eclipse' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

But eclipse is still showing and running in the system

Comment: Did you install Eclipse with apt? Could it be a Snap or something you installed directly from a .deb package? 

Comment: There does not seem to be any package called `eclipse` in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I installed it from the deb package. Now I have deleted the eclipse folder from the system so it is not running anymore but the main problem is that even though it has been deleted from the system, the icon is still showing in the search bar for application searc

Comment: Can you give a little more information about exactly how "you installed it from the deb package"? Did you download this deb package from somewhere? It isn't in the repos.

Comment: after downloading the deb package from the website, I extracted them and ran ```./eclipse-inst``` and then an interface was shown from which  i installed it

Comment: What is "the website"? I think you probably downloaded a tarball, not a deb, and this is why you can't remove it using the package system.

Comment: You should reverse the installation using the opposite procedure of how it was installed; you've been *vague* with regards how it was installed - where precise details are needed.  Look in your machine logs (if it was an *deb* package install it'll appear in *apt* logs for example; `/var/log/apt/history.log`)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you actually used the Eclipse Installer, which doesn't use the APT package management system. It just plops Eclipse into a folder on your system, and that's it.

To uninstall Eclipse, you should be able to just delete the following folders. **This will delete all installations of Eclipse on your system, so if you're trying to remove just one version, don't do this.** OK, here are the things to delete:

- `~/eclipse/`
- `~/.eclipse/`
- `~/p2/`

If you're done with any Eclipse projects, you may also want to delete `~/workspace/`. You may also want to search for any other Eclipse workspaces on your system and delete them, too - search for `.metadata` folders on your system, and that should find them.

You might also have other folders you want to delete - for instance, if you used Maven with Eclipse, you may want to get rid of "~/.m2/" (though be careful with this stuff, since some of that data may be shared with other IDEs on your system!)

Final note: This is just an adaption of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855742) by [kapex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897024/kapex) on Stack Overflow that has more info. The answer is regarding removing Eclipse from Windows, but the instructions appear to also work on Linux.